# Custom plugin, option to add a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, custom-controls

I'm trying to write my first small plugin and I've sort of hit a wall.

My plugin is a simple .replace() function that finds whatever the openReplace and closeReplace
values are and switches them with my tagOpen and tagClose values.

The problem I'm having is before `var colorText` is called that grabs my options I want to be able to add a class to the tagOpen value that is being used and be able to change it in my options, basically just let users who use this to have the freedom to use their own class names when they call the function and set a class name in the options.

Hope that makes sense and feel free to give me feedback on the code structure of my plugin.

Thanks

```
(function($){

  $.fn.TextColor = function(options) {  

    var defaults = {
      class            :'',
      openReplace      :'{',
      closeReplace     :'}',
      tagOpen          :'<span>',
      tagClose         :'</span>'
    };

    return this.each(function() {        

      if ( options ) { 
        $.extend( defaults, options );
      }

      var obj = $(this);

      //Add a var to be able to add a class to tagOpen here and replace with defaults.tagOpen in the colorText variable below

      var colorText = obj.html().replace(defaults.openReplace,defaults.tagOpen).replace(defaults.closeReplace,defaults.tagClose);

      obj.html(colorText);


    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a regex + building the tag with JQuery:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.TextColor = function(options) {

var defaults = {
  className        :'myClass',
  openReplace      :'{',
  closeReplace     :'}',
  openTag          :'<span>',
  closeTag         :'</span>'
};

if ( options ) { 
    $.extend( defaults, options );
 }

return this.each(function() {        
    var $obj = $(this);
    var html = = obj.html();
    var regex = new RegExp(defaults.openReplace + '(.+?)' + defaults.closeReplace, 'gi');

    html = html.replace(regex, function(outerMatch, innerMatch) {
         var wrapper = $("<div>");
         var tag = $(defaults.openTag)
                       .addClass(defaults.className)
                       .html(innerMatch)
                       .appendTo(wrapper);

     return wrapper.html();                 
   });

   obj.html(colorText);

});

}; })( jQuery );
```

note: you should probably refrain from using class as it is a reserved word in IE and might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help Guy, just needed to change a few lines to get rid of some errors and everything worked out great. Had a question though, would you mind explaining your code a bit. I would really much rather understand it than to copy and paste it. Not to sure what + '(.+?)' + is in the new RegExp and if you could explain the outerMatch, innerMatch function and why you have set up "var wrapper". If you could do that and help me understand this a little more that would be great! thanks man.

Comment: sure - 1. the reason to use 'new Regex()' rather than plain old /{(.+?)}/ syntax is we need a dynamically regex from string.
2. the replace function can get a method as arg. the method iterates on every match and replaces it with the return value of the function (very useful!). To make things better, it even receives two arguments - the match & the innermatch (anything within the bracets "()" in the regex). you can check the arguments by typing console.log(arguments) in the function withing the replace.
3. jquery lets you build html by $('<span') the wrapper is a way to get the outerHTML..